# Getting errors Working with HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

I have created a class that contains a `HashSet` to keep track of integer numbers from 1-10. I used the `Contain` method to check if a value is inserted in the `HashSet`, with a bool. Here is my code:

```
class BasicIntSet
{
    HashSet<int> intTest = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    bool has4 = intTest.Contains(4);    // Returns true
    bool has11 = intTest.Contains(11);  // Returns false
    bool result = intTest.IsSupersetOf(new[] { 4, 6, 7 });
}
```

My problem now is, that I get an error that says `"Error    1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"`

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you know that you can comment [on an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14882319/146622), for example if it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 4):

All your code is in the *class declaration*... you're declaring instance fields. You can't make one instance field initializer refer to another (or refer to `this` in any other way), hence the error.

Fixing it is simple - put your code into a method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class BasicIntSet
{
    static void Main()
    {
        HashSet<int> intTest = new HashSet<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        Console.WriteLine(intTest.Contains(4)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(intTest.Contains(11)); // False
        Console.WriteLine(intTest.IsSupersetOf(new[] { 4, 6, 7 })); // True
    }
}
```

Note that your original error has nothing to do with `HashSet<T>` at all. Here's just about the simplest example I can think of:

```
class BadFieldInitializers
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = x;
}
```

That gives the same error - because again, one field initializer (for `y`) refers to `this` implicitly.